# Is it possible to use free dynos for review apps by default?

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines, heroku-review-app

We are a team that uses Heroku pipeline. By default, each review app uses hobby dyno. Is it possible to configure the pipeline to use free dyno for each review app by default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of of the configuration options you can place inside of `app.json` can be used to configure the **number and type** of dynos used when spinning up your review app.

[Documentation app.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema)

[Configuring Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#configuration)

The majority of the configuration options you can use at the root of `app.json` can be overridden in the `environment.review` key.

**Example:**

```json
{
    "environments": {
        "review": {
            "formation": {
                "web": {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "size": "free"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```